# C++ application takes 100% cpu cycles after some period

Tags: c++, cpu, cpu-usage

In my application, I have used OOP's features like class, inheritance etc.
I haven't used any thread in application still after some period it takes 100% CPU cycles.
Can anyone help me to find out What are the possible causes?

Comment: without more information? probably not... EDIT: how many CPUs do you have?

Comment: and which OS do you use? Linux with the Top command shows 100% if 1 Core is 100% utilized and 200% is 2 Cores are 100% utilized. And so on.

Comment: You may want to run it in a debugger and interrupt it after a while, just to see where in the code it is. Perhaps it's trapped in an infinite loop.

Comment: It's not the features of a language used that matters here, it's more about the algorithm/design and also the idioms used.

Comment: Well, any application that does a lot of processing will use 100% CPU (or more, if it's multithreaded). If you think it's stuck, add some printouts or use debugger to see what's happening.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, how on earth can the presence or absence of interfaces directly affect CPU usage?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: My thoughts, exactly +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Most probable reason would be an infinite loop(as already mentioned by Jogojapan). And best way to find it out would be to use a debugger and see where the code is stuck when it starts utilizing high CPU)..

Comment: thanks KK.I tried with debugger but problem is not reproduced. I can see this problem only if I run my application for 1-2 days.

Comment: @Amar: If you have that time for testing, why not let it run in a debugger for three days or so, and pause once it gets stuck to see were the program is?

Comment: @Amar. Let it run for 2 days or more.. when you see that your application is eating up all the resources then you can attach your debugger to the application. 
Or else you can hace your code run in debugger from beginning as suggested by @ted(but I'd not advice it personally).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're running some function that takes a large amount of time to do a really complicated 'thing', it's likely being caused by some kind of loop that doesn't have a pause in it.  Look for something like `do {...} while (!exit);` to fix it, you'll need to call a function that yields time to the os, and put in an API call to the `sleep(x)` function which effectively pauses your program for 'x' milliseconds.  If you're using windows this can be done by `#include <windows.h>` and then putting `sleep(10);` at the end of the loop.  The '10' is arbitrary; but note that smaller values tend to act random, and anything less than 33 is fine if you have lots of graphics (for 30 fps), and 100 or so is good for event-driven things that mainly involve clicking or menus.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, CPU usage of 100% is of course not necessarily a problem. If the process performs a lot of calculations, rather than e.g. IO, 100% CPU usage may be perfectly healthy, and in fact desired.

But if indeed you feel it's using CPU cycles although it shouldn't, here are a few general strategies to deal with that:

1. Write code that isn't likely to cause such issues in the first place. Use unit tests (with good coverage of the input range), and avoid loops with overly complex exit conditions. (For simple or standard situations, using built-in algorithms like `std::for_each`, `std::generate` etc. also helps avoiding infinite loops.)
2. Use log messages so you can keep track of what you program is doing, even after days, by checking the log. If you worried about the added computational burden caused by lots of log messages, you can implement them so there are run-time, or even compile-time options to turn them on or off or select the level of detail. There are various logging frameworks to help (there is even an [SO question listing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696321/best-logging-framework-for-native-c), although it's closed and may be deleted).
3. If the above didn't help and you have a situation like the one described in your post, use a debugger to determine the part of the code your process gets stuck in. You can run the program in the debugger for several days or weeks if necessary. When it reaches the point of 100% CPU usage, interrupt and inspect the callstack to see where the process is. Infinite loops (or similar phenomena) may occur on a relatively high level, so you might need to walk up and down the stack to understand where the loop occurs. You can also continue the process and interrupt at a later point again.